# How to disable edit mode in particular cell ios?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

i created tableview in editable mode all tableview rows are contain (-) symbol, but i need some cells are not under editable mode ,if it is possible,
Thanks

Comment: Please review the `Tableview Programming Guide` as well as have a quick look at the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` references. It should be obvious which methods are appropriate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to apple documentation of UITableViewDataSource 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can use `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: In Swift it's - func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {}

Answer (score 11):

Yes reading the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) will shed some light on this problem. The method in question that will help you is: `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`

This should get you headed in the right direction.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL edit = NO;

    if(indexPath.row == 2) {

        edit = YES;
    }

    return edit;
}
```

Comment: +2 if I could! Cheers :)